# How to exit lightbox by clicking outside the box or hitting esc when combined with an image map

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, imagemap

I have adapted [this lightbox code](http://www.superiorwebsys.com/42-how-to-create-a-lightbox-to-display-text-or-images/) for a project I am working that involves image maps. Here is what it looks like in my project, I have this for each area element so that clicking on each one will open a different lightbox:

```
<body>
  <center><img src="Slides/Slide2.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;" alt="" USEMAP="#Map"></center>
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <div id="grayBG" class="grayBox" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="LightBox1" class="box_content" style="display:none;">
      <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr align="left" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
          <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:10px;"><div onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;" style="cursor:pointer;" align="right">
            <div>X</div>
            <object type="text/html" data="Content/2-1.html" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></object>
          </div>
          <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="145,365,540,365,540,430,144,430" onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </map>
```

The Javascript code I am using is the same as from the website linked above, I'll put it here for convenience:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
/* Superior Web Systems */ 
function displayHideBox(boxNumber) 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display=="none") { 
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="block"; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="none"; 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

I am currently only able to exit out of the lightbox by clicking on the "X" in the corner of the box. I want to be able to exit it by clicking anywhere outside of the box or by hitting the esc key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display=="none") { 
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="block"; 
    } else {        
 var currentLightbox = document.getElementById('LightBox' + boxNumber);
        if (!currentLightbox.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && currentLightbox.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container 
                || e.keyCode == 27 // if the user presses esc
        {
           document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="none"; 
           document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="none"; 
        }
    }
```

This part should go in the section with the else statement. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I am inserting it properly, when I put it in, the lightboxes do not appear anymore when clicked on. I am trying to put it right after the else statement and replacing what was there before.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Replace everything in the function and put this in.  Can you see if that would help? Also, did you check the console to see if any errors were outputted. I am unable to test it out myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if I need to make a change to the code in my body text now. Is there some place that I need to include the "currentLightbox" variable?

The console says there are no errors in the code.

Comment: You wouldn''t need to add it. I think the issue is the event handler that it is attached to. It only calls the function if the user clicks on the div. try to call the function displayHideBox() underneath your code and see if that might help.